# build a dict using dictionay-comprehension when I get keys and values from the same function

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Let's assume I have a complex function `get_stuff` that takes an int and returns a tuple, the 1st element is of type str. The following example has the same behavior but assume the real function is more complex and can't easily be split in two:

```
def get_stuff(x):
    return str(5*x),float(3*x)
```

What I want is to build a dict whose (key,value) pairs are the results of get_stuff when called on a specific set of integers. One way to do that would be:

```
def get_the_dict(set_of_integers):
    result = {}
    for i in set_of_integers:
        k,v = get_stuff(i)
        result[k] = v
    return result
```

I would rather use dict comprehension for that, but I don't know if it is possible to split the pair inside the comprehension to catch the key and the value separately.

```
def get_the_dict_with_comprehension(set_of_integers):
    return {get_stuff(i) for i in set_of_integers} #of course this doesn't work
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this, not quite a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict(get_stuff(i) for i in range(10))
```

Comment: Building a dictionary from a comprehension - that's close enough for jazz.

Comment: @Joffan From a generator expression, to be exact.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use a `dict` comprehension, you can do the following:

```
{k: v for k, v in [get_stuff(i) for i in set_of_integers]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a comprehension you can also map the set of integers to the `dict` constructor with the key-value pairs returned by `get_stuff`:

```
dict(map(get_stuff, set_of_integers))
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to this?

Comment: This is the most concise and elegant answer even though Python maintainers don't like `map`/`reduce` too much and prefer generator expressions instead.

Comment: Whether to use imperative style (with a comprehension) or functional style (with `map`) in this case comes down mostly to personal preferences, although using `map` makes it easier to apply parallel processing to speed up the transformation (by substituting `map` with `multiprocessing.Pool.map`, for example).